# NA returned by R while splitting date time group into date and time columns using POSIXct

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

dataframe heartrate has Id, date time group as character and value as the three variables.
Used the code for splitting date time group into separate columns for date and time but getting NA in the time field.

Used the following code

```
heartrate <- read_csv("../input/fitbit/Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16/heartrate_seconds_merged.csv")

head(heartrate)

str(heartrate)

glimpse(heartrate)

heartrate$New_date <- as.Date(heartrate$Time)

heartrate$New_time <- as.POSIXct(heartrate$Time, format = '%H:%M:%S')
```

The resulting dataframe shows NA in the time fields:

```
**Id             New_time        New_date        Value**
<dbl>            <dttm>          <date>          <dbl>
2022484408       NA              4-12-20            97
2022484408       NA              4-12-20           102
2022484408       NA              4-12-20           105
2022484408       NA              4-12-20           103
2022484408       NA              4-12-20           101
2022484408       NA              4-12-20            95
```

Can someone guide me to get the time values in HH:MM:SS?
Thanks

Comment: We need to see some example original values of `heartrate$Time`. If you were able to convert it to a Date, then it is probably of type DateTime? So HMS format isn't going to work.

Comment: R's `POSIXt` (generated by `as.POSIXct`) is not a time data type, it is a date/time data type, which means it must have date as well as time. If you really need to use time-of-day completely separate from the date, then look into helper packages/functions including `lubridate::hms`, which produces a number-like field of just time. Other than this, there's nothing we can do given the lack of sample data.

Comment: The date time was imported as numeric. Your first task is to convert to character. The leading digits are probably YYYY part of date time but can’t tell what the rest are even after looking up Fitbit date time formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you to get that to work:

```
# Create a character vector of dates and times
dates_times <- c("2022-01-01 12:00:00", "2022-02-01 15:30:00", "2022-03-01 08:45:00")
dates_times <- as.POSIXct(dates_times, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(dates_times)

# "2022-01-01 12:00:00 NZDT" "2022-02-01 15:30:00 NZDT" "2022-03-01 08:45:00 NZDT"

# Use the format function to extract the date and time
date <- format(dates_times, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
time <- format(dates_times, format = "%H:%M:%S")

# Print the result
print(date)

# "2022-01-01" "2022-02-01" "2022-03-01"

print(time)

# "12:00:00" "15:30:00" "08:45:00"
```